# Using and injecting Angular $templateCache with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs

I do a `grunt serve:dist` and within I build with `grunt-contrib-requirejs` an `all.js` file based on my RequireJS `main.js` file which have `require.config` and a `require` section.

I think `all.js` should be in my distribution that file which I have to include on startup in my index.html, because everything is in there. Is this right?

```
<script src="require.js" data-main="all.js"></script>
```

I also create based on all my template HTML files a template JavaScript file with `ngTemplates` and bootstrap it so the template file named `templates.js` looks like this:

```
define([
  'angular'
], function(angular) {
  angular.module('MyApp.templates', []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    'use strict';
    $templateCache.put('templates/MyTest.html',
      "<h1>Title</h1>\r" +
      // ...
    // other put on $templateCache
  }]);
});
```

So I have a `$templateCache` which I want to use. But I do not how this can be done. I think I have to load the `templates.js` because it is not included in `all.js` and therefore I should inject it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I found a way to solve it.
Basically, I have `templates.js` to return just a function to inject to run block.

For example: `templates.js`

```
define([], function()){
    return ['$templateCache", function($templateCache){
        'use strict';
        $templateCache.put('templates/MyTest.html',
        "<h1>Title</h1>\r" +
        // ...
        // other put on $templateCache
    }];
}
```

and then, in your `app.js` file, you can inject this function into run block

```
define(['templates'], function(templates){
    angular.module('app')
        .run(templates);
})
```

I hope this helped, please let me know if you are not clear with something.